# Failed to pull docker image from azure container registry while training

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run a job on Azure Ml using Azure-cli. The training code is present in a custom docker image uploaded to Azure container registry.
After firing this command

```
az ml job create -f test.yaml --resource-group DefaultResourceGroup-EUS2 --workspace-name test-airflow
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to pull Docker image prateek2001.azurecr.io/test/dataprep:latest. This error may occur because the compute could not authenticate with the Docker registry to pull the image. 
If using ACR please ensure the ACR has Admin user enabled or a Managed Identity with `AcrPull` access to the ACR is assigned to the compute.
If the ACR Admin user's password was changed recently it may be necessary to synchronize the workspace keys.
```

I have tried the following things:

```
Check if the ACR Admin user is enabled:

Log in to the Azure portal.
Go to the Azure Container Registry you are trying to use.
Under the "Access keys" section, check if the Admin user is enabled.
If it is not enabled, enable it by clicking the "Enable" button.
Check if a Managed Identity with "AcrPull" access is assigned to the compute:

Go to the compute where you are running the Docker image.
Check if a Managed Identity is assigned to the compute.
If a Managed Identity is not assigned, assign one by following the steps in the Azure 
documentation.
Assign the "AcrPull" role to the Managed Identity on the Azure Container Registry.
```

But the error still continues. Can't figure out why it is happening.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).